# Tensor differential equations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, general-relativity

I am reading Ringstrom's book *The Cauchy problem in General Relativity*, But I don't really understand Chapter 12 associating to tensor equations. I want to read some other material about this. Could anyone suggest me some books about tensor differential equations?

I want to learn something about the analysis of the existence and uniqueness of solution to tensor equations.

Comment: This might be usual: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386055/how-to-solve-a-tensor-differential-equation

Comment: Sorry, I want to learn something about the analysis about the existence and uniqueness of solution to tensor equations. not just to solve some. but still thank you.

Comment: The tensor case is not any different from the scalar case. Generally what you do is that you scalarise the equation by working with the components of the tensor in relation to a coordinate system. Write out the equation for the components using Christoffel symbols, and then appeal to general statements concerning the principal part of the equation you've written down.

Comment: @WillieWong I see. Thanks for your answer.